# Finding the origin of a package not from an official repository?

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, package-management

I have couchdb 1.1.0-1 install on Debian Squeeze. According to [debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=couchdb) this is not one of their official versions. So I tried:

```
apt-cache policy couchdb
couchdb:
  Installed: 1.1.0-1
  Candidate: 1.1.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.11.0-2.3 0
        500 http://ftp.nz.debian.org squeeze/main Packages
```

But this doesn't help me any further on how this package got installed? Here's the sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
deb-src http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main

deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile squeeze/volatile main
deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile squeeze/volatile main
```

Comment: How many people have access to `sudo`? Could it have been manually downloaded & installed via `dpkg -i`? Could a [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) / [checkinstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) generated .deb be in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess someone pulled it off unstable/testing at some point in time.

While there is no current package `1.1.0-1` in the repository a quick look at the changelog shows that one did exist in the repo back in 2011 between April and August.

http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/c/couchdb/couchdb_1.2.0-5_changelog

```
couchdb (1.1.0-2) unstable; urgency=low
...
 -- Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.hu>  Sat, 06 Aug 2011 09:33:58 +0200

couchdb (1.1.0-1) unstable; urgency=low

  * New upstream release (closes: #590334).
  * Version jQuery dependency (closes: #582022, #614941).
  * Empty dependency_libs in *.la (closes: #621202).
  * Drop pid.patch , applied upstream and drop icu-config.patch not needed.
  * Fix postrm , remove_file_collection is missing.
  * Fix several lintian errors and warnings:
    - add patch to implement force-reload initscript option
    - use real erlang dependency, not just the virtual ABI one
    - remove embedded jquery.form.js , depend on its package
    - remove var/run/couchdb from the package, it'll be created on demand

 -- Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.hu>  Thu, 14 Apr 2011 11:56:01 +0200
```

Comment: This could be it, thanks! I've managed to find the source and *.deb file on this server so it looks like a package was built from source and installed around this time. Still, I would like to know if there's a way to find this out (e.g. audit record, install history) aside from searching the OS for *.deb files and assuming that's where it came from.